# How to put a check on empty dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

In my code,

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="roomnumbers" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"> </asp:DropDownList>
```

gets values on another dropdownlist's OnSelectedIndexChanged and without that, it stays empty. Now how to do I use this empty dropdownlist 'roomnumbers' in if-else condition? I've tried:

```
if (roomnumbers.selecteditem == null)
// code
if (roomnumbers.selectedindex == -1)
//code 
if(roomnumbers.selecteditem.tostring() == "")
// code
```

but none of these worked and I still get System.NullReferenceException error. Can someone help me with this? I mean like in TextBox, we can use string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox1.Text) then what will we use for DropDownlist?

Comment: " and if " what language is that ?

Comment: @Aristos its asp.net, and is a mistake, let me edit it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the binding mechanism used.
In this case it looks like you are using standard webforms type stuff so a simple jquery selector may be enough to determine if the list has any items fro mthere you can decide weatehr to further ask for the selected one ...

On the server

```
if (roomnumbers.Items.Count > 0) 
{
       // get selected value
    }
    else 
    {
      // dropdown has no items
    }
```

On the client

```
var hasItems = $("#roomnumbers select").length;
if(hasItems) {
   // get selected value
}
else {
  // dropdown has no items
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this. Just count the items in the DropDownList.

```
if (roomnumbers.Items.Count == 0)
{
    //no items loaded
}
else
{
    //there are items in the list
}
```

Comment: actually the dropdownlist is empty with no items loaded into it and I have to use this in the if-else condition. If elements are loaded into it then I'll be performing different set of codes.

Comment: Just use an `if else` statement.